# How do I use the pipe operator or something related to break a pipeline into two steps?

Tags: r, sparklyr, magrittr

Is there a way to break this into two steps so that the ml_logistic_regression() can be applied separately to flights_pipeline?

Below is working code for the pipeline:

```
flights_pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(
    tbl = df
    ) %>%
  ft_binarizer(
    input_col = "dep_delay",
    output_col = "delayed",
    threshold = 15
  ) %>%
  ft_bucketizer(
    input_col = "sched_dep_time",
    output_col = "hours",
    splits = c(400, 800, 1200, 1600, 2000, 2400)
  )  %>%
  ft_r_formula(delayed ~ month + day + hours + distance) %>% 
  ml_logistic_regression()
```

This is my attempt, I'd like to break it into two steps - something like this:

```
flights_pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(
    tbl = df
    ) %>%
  ft_binarizer(
    input_col = "dep_delay",
    output_col = "delayed",
    threshold = 15
  ) %>%
  ft_bucketizer(
    input_col = "sched_dep_time",
    output_col = "hours",
    splits = c(400, 800, 1200, 1600, 2000, 2400)
  )  %>%
  ft_r_formula(delayed ~ month + day + hours + distance)

flights_pipeline_with_model <- flights_pipeline %>% 
  ml_logistic_regression()
```

Comment: Yes you can — exactly as you did it. What’s wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I see, okay thank you. Sorry, seems like my error is coming from a different place after all. I appreciate your quick response and clarity on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear based on the description and the OP's second code block.  If the intention is to create an object within the pipe and continue with the pipe, perhaps `pipeR` could help

```
library(pipeR)
ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
  ft_dplyr_transformer(
    tbl = df
    ) %>%
  ft_binarizer(
    input_col = "dep_delay",
    output_col = "delayed",
    threshold = 15
  ) %>%
  ft_bucketizer(
    input_col = "sched_dep_time",
    output_col = "hours",
    splits = c(400, 800, 1200, 1600, 2000, 2400)
  )  %>%
  ft_r_formula(delayed ~ month + day + hours + distance) %>% 
  (~flights_pipeline) %>>%  
  ml_logistic_regression()
```